# Transition Matrix with Python

Tags: python

I am using this transition matrix to find the states of bases AGCT. Here is the matrix:
pij = 0.01
pii = 0.97
P = np.array( [[pii, pij, pij, pij], [pij, pii, pij, pij], [pij, pij, pii, pij],[pij, pij, pij, pii]] )

1. how do I find the probability of being in state A, G, C and T after 20 steps?
2. What about the probability of being in state G at all 20 steps and 3. The probability of being in state G after 20 steps and having visited at least one other state {A, C, T} during the 19 other transitions

Here was my attempt but the probabilities are wrong:

```
import numpy as np
# Transition matrix
pij = 0.01
pii = 0.97
P = np.array([[pii, pij, pij, pij], 
              [pij, pii, pij, pij], 
              [pij, pij, pii, pij], 
              [pij, pij, pij, pii]])

# Initial probability distribution
init_dist = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0]) # starting from state G

# Probability of being in each state after 20 steps
prob_20_steps = np.linalg.matrix_power(P, 20) @ init_dist

# Probability of being in state A, G, C, T after 20 steps
print(f"P(A) = {prob_20_steps[0]:.4f}")
print(f"P(G) = {prob_20_steps[1]:.4f}")
print(f"P(C) = {prob_20_steps[2]:.4f}")
print(f"P(T) = {prob_20_steps[3]:.4f}")
# G in 20 steps

prob_g_20_steps = (np.linalg.matrix_power(P, 20)[1, 1])**20
print(f"P(G at all 20 steps) = {prob_g_20_steps:.4f}")

#G visited at least one state
prob_g_visited_20_steps = prob_20_steps[1] - prob_g_20_steps
print(f"P(G after 20 steps and having visited at least one other state) = {prob_g_visited_20_steps:.4f}")
```

Would appreciate a modified code or help on how to print the right probabilities.

Comment: Why are the probabilities wrong? What should they be, and why, and what does your code say they are?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. As far as I can tell, your code is correct here
2. You need to calculate the probability distribution at each step and look at the G probability.

   `G_prob_steps = [(np.linalg.matrix_power(P, i) @ init_dist)[1] for i in range(0, 21)]`
3. Probability of G at 20 steps having visited another state at least once = Probability of G at 20 steps - Probability of G at all steps.

   `G_20_w_visit = (np.linalg.matrix_power(P, 20) @ init_dist)[1] - 0.97**20`